# Request method 'POST' not supported Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, http-post

I've a spring form and when I click a submit button I would like to send a list of elements previously updated.

Here's the jsp :

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="listeBlocs" action="saveFiche">
    <c:forEach var="oneBloc" items="${listeBlocs}" varStatus="status">
        <h5 class="col m12 s10">${oneBloc.typeBloc}</h5>
        <tr>
        <td><textarea  name="listeBlocs[${status.index}].blocContenu" >${oneBloc.blocContenu}</textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    <input type="submit" value="saveFiche" />

</form:form>
```

Here's the destination Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveFiche", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private ModelAndView updateBloc(@ModelAttribute("listeBlocs") List<Bloc> lblocs) {
    BlocDAO blocDAO = new BlocDAO();
    for (Bloc b : lblocs) {
        System.out.println("------------\nNouveau bloc : " + b.getblocContenu());
        blocDAO.update(b);
    }

    return new ModelAndView("confirmation_update");
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try with a public method

Comment: Hi @tempusfugit I tried your solution, but same error